# VLAN annotation information

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure, vlan

We have some VLANs, and I would like to add some annotation for each VLAN, for example, to add information about which team it belongs to and the purpose. It could be a list of key:value1,value2 pairs or some way to derive that information.

After I logged in to SL account, when I go to "Network -> IP Management -> VLANs", there is "Notes" field, however, it is not editable. Is there a way to update this field (eg. via API calls), and if so, would there be limitation of the content?

Would tags be another way to address this issue? What is the best way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

it is not possible to edit the notes what you can do is:

1. Edit the name of the Vlan
2. Add a tag

You can edit the name of the VLAN using the control portal, if you want to do it using the API this is a RESTful example:

```
POST https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/$VLANID/editObject

PAyload:

{
    "parameters": [
          {
              "name":"myname"
          }
        ]
}
```

To add tag to the VLAN you can use this RESTful:

```
POST https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Network_Vlan/$VLANID/setTags

payload:

{
    "parameters": ["tag1,tag2,tag3"]
}
```

To get the list the VLANs and their tags you can use this RESTful:

```
GET https://$USERNAME:$APIKEY@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getNetworkVlans?objectMask=mask[id,name,tagReferences[id,tag]]
```

Note: For all the examples replace the variables with the prefix "$" with your data

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there a way to add tags on the SL portal?